# What does "和尚撞了道士" mean?

Tags: meaning, topolect

In the song《[掐死大象的蚂蚁](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Q7zFZncboA)》by Bridge and 二毛 there's a [bar](http://www.mc1314.com/news/news-7807.html) by *twenty-cents*(?) that goes:

> 咋个回事咋个回事
>   十点半还不晓得回家
>   问起咋子问起咋子
>   也不晓得打个电话
>   有事有事安啥子事嘛啥子事嘛
>   和尚撞了道士上房揭瓦你要造次

The part that is tripping me up is: *和尚撞了道士*. Most search results online for 和尚撞了道士 just come back to the lyrics for this song.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: this is a Sichuanese song.

---

Let's start with something you'll recognize:

> Q: 怎么办？
>   A: 凉拌！

---

In Sichuanese this is called: 展嘴巴劲 or 扳嘴巴劲 or 展牙巴劲. That is relevant because this is a form of Sichuanese 展嘴巴劲. It goes a little something like this:

> A: 有事
>   B: 和尚赶道士

It is something that is said when someone thinks that you are coming up with a pretext or an excuse to be busy rather that actually having anything to do.

There also seems to be quite a few variants on the phrase. Obviously from the question we have: 和尚撞了道士. A more common variant is 和尚赶道士. Online you can also find examples of: 和尚做道士 and 和尚撵道士.

---

There are a bunch of these in Sichuanese:

- 开腔嘛——开腔<枪>打死人
- 负责——负他妈的床坝箦
- 赔——我陪你坐
- 真的——煮的哟
- 看嘛<马>——看牛哦
- 不敢<赶>——过吆
- 好久<酒>——没得好菜
- 长——往土坝里长
- 结婚——脑壳昏
- 花——眼睛花
- 钱——夹火钳
- 等于是——二加二等于四
- 啥子——帕子，帕子搭到脸上
- 没关系——没川戏，没川戏看电影嘛